# can't add geometry column with EPSG -1 to postgres table

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I have a postgres 9.x database with postgis 2.3 and I have created a new schema named `scuma` and I followed this [tutorial](https://postgis.net/2017/11/07/tip-move-postgis-schema/)

in order to make the postgis functions available for the new schema but when I try to execute

```
SELECT AddGeometryColumn('scuma','table1','attr6',-1,'POINT',2);
```

I get this error

```
ERROR:  type "public.geometry" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT public.ST_SRID('POINT EMPTY'::public.geometry)
                                         ^
QUERY:  SELECT public.ST_SRID('POINT EMPTY'::public.geometry)
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function addgeometrycolumn(character varying,character varying,character varying,character varying,integer,character varying,integer,boolean) line 56 at assignment
SQL statement "SELECT AddGeometryColumn('',$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7)"
PL/pgSQL function addgeometrycolumn(character varying,character varying,character varying,integer,character varying,integer,boolean) line 5 at SQL statement

********** Error **********

ERROR: type "public.geometry" does not exist
SQL state: 42704
Context: PL/pgSQL function addgeometrycolumn(character varying,character varying,character varying,character varying,integer,character varying,integer,boolean) line 56 at assignment
SQL statement "SELECT AddGeometryColumn('',$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7)"
PL/pgSQL function addgeometrycolumn(character varying,character varying,character varying,integer,character varying,integer,boolean) line 5 at SQL statement
```

I see all the postgis functions added to my new schema and I have passed the schema name as an argument to the function so I have no idea why it is looking for public. Is this a bug in postgis?
If I run this query it works:

```
SELECT AddGeometryColumn('scuma','table1','attr6',4328,'POINT',2);
```

Update: here is the output for `\dx`

```
gogu=# \dx
                                                                   List of installed extensions
         Name             | Version |   Schema   |                                                     Description                                                     
------------------------------+---------+------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
address_standardizer         | 2.3.3   | public     | Used to parse an address into constituent elements. Generally used to support geocoding address normalization step.
address_standardizer_data_us | 2.3.3   | public     | Address Standardizer US dataset example
fuzzystrmatch                | 1.1     | public     | determine similarities and distance between strings
plpgsql                      | 1.0     | pg_catalog | PL/pgSQL procedural language
postgis                      | 2.3.3   | scuma      | PostGIS geometry, geography, and raster spatial types and functions
postgis_tiger_geocoder       | 2.3.3   | tiger      | PostGIS tiger geocoder and reverse geocoder
postgis_topology             | 2.3.3   | topology   | PostGIS topology spatial types and functions
(7 rows)

gogu=#
```

Comment: Hej Corneliu. It seems postgis isn't properly installed in the current database. If you have the right permissions, could you try a `DROP EXTENSION postgis;` and a `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;`?

Comment: Or even better, try `\dx` on your `psql` and let me know what it says.

Comment: Hey Jim. Please see my updated original post for the output of `\dx`

Comment: Also I run the DROP and CREATE commands and they simply remove the functions from my custom schema and adds them back to the public schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following that tutorial, you moved all the postgis stuff to the "scuma" schema.

So st_srid is now defined in the scuma schema, not in the public one.

So you have to use scuma.st_srid instead of public.st_srid.

Note that you don't need to move postgis functions from "public" in order to use them in other schemas.

Comment: Thank you. And how can I use the postgis functions in other schemas without moving them? By qualifying them with the public schema name?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your just trying to get the `postgis` feature in the wrong schema. If the extension isn't used at the `public` schema, you can move it to `scuma` like this

```
ALTER EXTENSION postgis SET SCHEMA scuma;
```

Alternatively you can keep it in the public schema, but you will need to specify where the extension is, as mentioned above by @fradal83.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I did a few tests and it seems that I was overdoing it. I think I must keep the postgis functions in the public schema and use them in a different schema by passing that schema as an argument in the postgis function like i was already doing. Moving the postgis functions was wrong because that seems to introduce bugs. I still need to do a few more tests before I will accept fradal83's answer

Comment: Moving the extension shouldn't introduce any bugs (maybe regarding permissions?), but keeping it at public is indeed an elegant solution. Good luck!

Comment: Well, no software should ever introduce any bugs and yet... :-)
I think the bug here is that if you move the postgis functions to a custom schema, those functions call other functions and expect those functions to be in a certain place and when they are not found then the calling function crashes.